# React Native Drawer Navigator Icon Position

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I hope that all is well. I am trying to reposition the icon from `Drawer.Navigator` and resize it. Otherwise, I would like to know how to hide the icon since I have my icon already. What happened is I needed to import `DrawerActions` for my icon to show the nav and its options. After the import and the restructuring of the code a little bit, I realized I ended with two icons, as demonstrated below... I would like to be able to move the `Drawer.Navigator` icon in place of my icon and resize it or hide it and use my icon. I have included my code below. Any help would suffice. Thank you in advance for your help.

Two Navicon

[image: Two Icon]

Code:

```js
//Dependencies
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { AsyncStorage, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { DrawerActions, NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


//Screens
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Logout from './screens/Logout';

//Code
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const StackedScreens = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
      initialRouteName='Dashboard'
      screenOptions={headerStyle(navigation)}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} options={{drawerLabel: 'Dashboard'}}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{drawerLabel: 'Login'}}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={Logout} options={{drawerLabel: 'Logout'}}/>            
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['purple', 'gold']} style={styles.linearBGContainer}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <StackedScreens/>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </LinearGradient>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const headerStyle = (navigation) => {
  return {
    title: 'Catching Souls',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'purple' },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    headerRight: () => 
        (
          <Icon name='menu' size={50} color='white'
            onPress={()=> navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
          />
        ),
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  linearBGContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set [headerLeft](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerleft) to `false` to hide the left side of the header.

```
...
drawerPosition: 'right',
headerLeft: false,
headerRight: () => 
...
```

Comment: Let’s say if i decided to place a logo in place of the drawe nav. Will it overwrite the drawer.nav icon?